# Возвращение множества из функции на СИ для postgres

Tags: c, postgresql

предположим что есть некоторая функция которая возвращает множество:(небольшой псевдокод)

```
Datum foo(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
FuncCallContext     *funcctx;
// необходимые объявления
 if (SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL())
{
// часть функции которая вызывается для первого раза
char* ptr=palloc(10*sizeof(char));
ptr=какая нибудь строка.
// какой то код
funcctx = SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT();
funcctx->user_fctx=(void*)ptr;
}
if (call_cntr < max_calls)   
{
 values = (char **) palloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
 values[0] = (char *) palloc(4 * sizeof(char));
// дальше идет формирование кортежей и загоняем в датум и возвращаем 
 SRF_RETURN_NEXT(funcctx, result);
}else
  {
    SRF_RETURN_DONE(funcctx);
  }
}
```

После того как эту функцию я зарегистрирую, я её вызываю в запросе. В результате выполнения функции должна быть возвращена таблица с одним столбцом и с данными в каждой строке. По факту когда эта функция выполняется корректно данные отображаются только в первой строке а в остальных мусор. Я так понял это все дело в функции palloc которая выделяет память и после выполнения функции память освобождается. а указатель funcctx->user_fctx после первой итерации становится висячим. Но когда я изменил функцию palloc в строчке 
char* ptr=palloc(10*sizeof(char));
на malloc то все работает так как нужно. У меня вопрос как быть? в доках  пишут что рекомендуется использовать palloc  вместо malloc

Answer (score 1):

Постгрес что бы контролировать распределение памяти использует механизм контекстов, т. е. любая память которая должна быть выделена она регистрируется где-то в контексте, а когда приходит время весь контекст освобождается и возвращается в общую кучу. Контекст - это структура вида:

```
  typedef struct MemoryContextData
{
    NodeTag     type;           /* identifies exact kind of context */
    /* these two fields are placed here to minimize alignment wastage: */
    bool        isReset;        /* T = no space alloced since last reset */
    bool        allowInCritSection; /* allow palloc in critical section */
    const MemoryContextMethods *methods;    /* virtual function table */
    MemoryContext parent;       /* NULL if no parent (toplevel context) */
    MemoryContext firstchild;   /* head of linked list of children */
    MemoryContext prevchild;    /* previous child of same parent */
    MemoryContext nextchild;    /* next child of same parent */
    const char *name;           /* context name (just for debugging) */
    const char *ident;          /* context ID if any (just for debugging) */
    MemoryContextCallback *reset_cbs;   /* list of reset/delete callbacks */
} MemoryContextData;
```

Для работы с контекстом есть методы которые упакованы тоже в структуру как указатели на функции:

```
    typedef struct MemoryContextMethods
{
    void       *(*alloc) (MemoryContext context, Size size);
    /* call this free_p in case someone #define's free() */
    void        (*free_p) (MemoryContext context, void *pointer);
    void       *(*realloc) (MemoryContext context, void *pointer, Size size);
    void        (*reset) (MemoryContext context);
    void        (*delete_context) (MemoryContext context);
    Size        (*get_chunk_space) (MemoryContext context, void *pointer);
    bool        (*is_empty) (MemoryContext context);
    void        (*stats) (MemoryContext context, MemoryStatsPrintFunc printfunc, 
void *passthru, MemoryContextCounters *totals);
#ifdef MEMORY_CONTEXT_CHECKING
    void        (*check) (MemoryContext context);
#endif
} MemoryContextMethods;
```

Функции palloc и free являются обертками над этими методами. palloc определяет текущий контекст, выделяет память(внутри вызывает malloc), регистрирует выделенную память(сохраняет указатель на начало куска памяти в контексте и скорее всего какую-нибудь еще служебную информацию) и возвращает указатель на выделенный кусок памяти. Освобождение происходит либо при вызове pfree либо когда контекст целиком очищается.
Возвращаясь к моей проблеме: почему при использовании palloc все крашилось, а при malloc работало но время от времени выходили кракозябры или вообще возвращались пусты строки. Дело в том что я прежде чем вызвать palloc не создал контекст памяти. И когда происходил вызов palloc регистрировать память негде было. При вызове malloc выделялась память туда загонялись данные, но выделение памяти проходило в обход контекстной системы. После первого вызова функции для первой строки память освободилась, но указатель funcctx->user_fctx указывал уже на кусок памяти, который находился в куче. Тут как раз мы получаем неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте рассмотрим какую-нибудь из штатных небольших функций. Например, `unnest`, разворачивающую массив в набор записей.

Определена функция `unnest` вот так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.unnest(anyarray)
 RETURNS SETOF anyelement
 LANGUAGE internal
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT ROWS 100
AS $function$array_unnest$function$
```

Что можно посмотреть через `sf unnest(anyarray)` в `psql`, затем смотрим как определена C функция `array_unnest` в файле [`src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c#L5883), всего 80 строк в длину и вполне пригодна для использования в качестве эталона реализации.

Вы верно определили, что ваша ссылка полученная из `palloc` теряет значение при последующем вызове и верно, причина тому механизм `memory context` реализованный в `postgresql`, который помогает очищать память. Чтобы закрепить кусочек памяти за собой, необходимо переключиться на уже созданный вызовом `SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT` новый `memory context` через

```
oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(funcctx->multi_call_memory_ctx);
```

Попутно сохранив предыдущий контекст памяти. Затем что-то делаете полезное/нужное, но перед возвращением из функции вы должны вернуться на изначальный контекст вызовом

```
MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);
```

Если же вызывать напрямую `malloc`, то указатели полностью в вашем распоряжении, но это приведёт к утечкам памяти. Например, если ваша функция была остановлена через `pg_cancel_backend` либо по какой-то другой причине была отменена (например, любой ошибкой в других функциях этого запроса) - у вашего кода нет вообще возможности вызвать `free` чтобы прибраться за собой. Тогда как все созданные при выполнении запроса `memory context` будут автоматически очищены при завершении обработки запроса.